# system::containerStartTime is not working

Tags: ssis

I have SSIS package which has few task(Execute SQL Tasks, Data flow task).I have two event handlers(OnPostExecute,OnError) for custom logging on package level.

I am using **system::containerStartTime** for the TaskStartTime(dateTime) on OnPostExecute event handler. But it's not inserting the correct start time. always all the tasks has the same time with milliseconds different. but there is minute of difference in the different task to start.

it's look like to me it's static variable which sets at the start of the package if this is the case than what is the difference between system:starttime and system:containerStartTime.

**This variable should show the same time which appear against each task as start time in execution result tab in Visual studio.**

please let me know how i get the correct start time of each tasks in the package.

Thanks,
Zaim Raza.

Answer (score 0):

containerStartTime is the time of the container of the task not the tasks themselves. 
I'm afraid there is no system variable for time at task level as per Microsoft documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables

One thing you can do is save the time to a user variable at the beginning or immediately before the tasks being monitored and use this on your event handler.